# Prevent AEM edit window from inheriting component style

Tags: html, css, jsp, aem

For various reasons, I have a component par section that uses the following style:

```
width: 250px;
margin-left: -76px;
```

This code increases the width of all components in the par and, for my purpose, centers it.

The issue I'm seeing now is that the AEM edit window programatically inherits the style of the par or its components as inline style.  That means the width of the edit window stretches to ~3000px, so content editors can't see the left and right edges of the edit window.

Is there any way to either limit the scope of the style to only the components or specifically remove the styles from the edit windows?

AEM version 6.1, class UI

Comment: It might be helpful for others to know your AEM version and if you are using Classic or Touch UI.

Comment: Can you add a classed div around the par within the component and localize the style?

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume those styles are attached to your parsys via a class? Why not restrict the addition of the class based on wcmmode.edit || wcmInit.isTouchAuthoring || wcmmode.design